# Damaged GPIO4 1w

Tags: 1-wire

My system was working 100% with two sensors on the GPIO 4 for 1w. The damn wire broke and think I damaged the GPIO 4 pin as the sensors aren't being registered. Could I use a different GPIO pin? My boot/cmdline.txt looks like this: dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev//mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck repair=yes rootwait modules-load=dwc2,g_serial
Any help please. Would prefer to not buy another pi. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look in `/boot/config.txt` for the 1-wire configuration.

Change it according to the details given in `/boot/overlays/README`

Perhaps test your GPIO.

https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing

Answer (score 0):

edit `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=5
```

w1 driver will use gpiopin 5 after reboot.

AND/OR

```
# cd /sys/bus/w1/devices/
# ls
28-000009572989  28-000009583ac3  w1_bus_master1
# cd 28-000009572989
# cat temperature 
23187
```

do a `ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/` to see if the system
has found any w1 devices at all

23187 = 23.187°C